# Eleventy/11ty deployment via github actions build failure using liquid template language

Tags: jekyll, github-actions, github-pages, eleventy

When trying to deploy an Eleventy blog via github pages, a seperate workflow is auto added named `pages build and deployment`.

However the issue arises with the `build with jekyll` process step, as my blog uses liquid templating language and syntaxes conflict. For example, a file `about.html` in the root directory uses `_includes\about.liquid` and the build process issues the following error:

```
Liquid Exception: Invalid syntax for include tag. File contains invalid characters or sequences: "author.liquid" Valid syntax: {% include file.ext param='value' param2='value' %} in src/about.html
```

The `build.yml` file:

```
name: Build Eleventy

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}

      - name: Install dependencies & build
        run: |
          npm ci
          npm run build
      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
        with:
          publish_dir: ./_site
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

This workflow gets a clean pass but its the other auto added one that's causing trouble.

The resources I've followed to deploy 11ty sites using Github Actions avoids the  `pages build and deployment` auto workflow since all of them are posted before [the new workflow was added by github](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-12-16-github-pages-using-github-actions-for-builds-and-deployments-for-public-repositories/).

My question is, am I missing anything? Any new plugins perhaps for Jekyll compatibility to deploy perhaps? Can I disable the workflow and thus follow the legacy codes to deploy?

Comment: Do you have a link to your GitHub repository?

Comment: sure.
https://github.com/riffAt2013/riffAt2013.github.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're not using Jekyll to build your site, you can disable building with Jekyll by adding [an empty `.nojekyll` file to the root of your repository](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/about-github-pages#static-site-generators).

In your case, this file would be on the `main` branch and should prevent GitHub from trying to build with Jekyll.